# Reading ellipsoid parameters using PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

I would like to retrieve the semi-major axis of ellipsoid of a layer (any layer) using Python API. It seems that `crs` class can read only the ellipsoid acronym (?) Apparently, `QgsDistanceArea` class reads all ellipsoid parameters, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem you can also get the [WKT](https://docs.oracle.com/html/A88805_01/sdo_cs_c.htm#887173)(well known text) as  QString (using [toWkt()](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#a55e62f3f587e9de20ed911d26d12f499) ).

You can then parse your WKT to extract the properties of your ellipsoid

```
<spheroid> ::=
     SPHEROID ["<name>", <semi major axis>, <inverse flattening> ]
```